# Inconsistencies populating an array with members from a split array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am struggling with a program I'm creating for Excel using VBA.  The ultimate intent of the program is to read specific elements of a text file into an Excel spreadsheet based upon the user's selection of one of those elements through a userform listbox.  Please refer to my code below which is for the section of my program pertaining to 1) populating the listbox with the job set numbers and 2) populating specific arrays containing the desired data I need from the very large comma-delimited text file:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Declare variables
    Const CMMData As String = "\\ATSTORE01\CMMData\21064D\21064D-OP400.dat"
    Dim strSN() As String
    Dim strSet() As String
    Dim strFF() As String
    Dim strVHCC() As String
    Dim strVHCCMID() As String
    Dim strVHCVMID() As String
    Dim strVHCV() As String
    Dim strHWCC() As String
    Dim strHWCCMID() As String
    Dim strHWCVMID() As String
    Dim strHWCV() As String
    Dim LineData As String
    Dim SplitData() As String
    Dim LineIter As Long
    'Populate Set Number Listbox
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(CMMData, ForReading)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                LineData = .ReadLine
                SplitData = Split(LineData, ",", 154, vbTextCompare)
                'Extracting Serial Number
                ReDim Preserve strSN(0 To LineIter)
                strSN(UBound(strSN)) = SplitData(0)
                'Extracting Set Number
                ReDim Preserve strSet(0 To LineIter)
                strSet(UBound(strSet)) = SplitData(1)
                'Extracting Final Flow Area
                ReDim Preserve strFF(0 To LineIter)
                strFF(UBound(strFF)) = SplitData(14)
                'Extracting /V/ To Hook CC
                ReDim Preserve strVHCC(0 To LineIter)
                strVHCC(UBound(strVHCC)) = SplitData(31)
                Set_Select.AddItem SplitData(1)
                LineIter = LineIter + 1
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
    End With
    For LineIter = LBound(strFF) To UBound(strFF)
        MsgBox strFF(LineIter)
    Next LineIter
End Sub
```

The area of the above code where I am having trouble is as follows:

```
'Extracting /V/ To Hook CC
ReDim Preserve strVHCC(0 To LineIter)
strVHCC(UBound(strVHCC)) = SplitData(31)
```

The code populates the split arrays up to (30).  For arrays (31) and above, I get a "Subscript out of range" error.  I have spent considerable time trying to determine the error but have been unsuccessful.  I am also quite new to working with arrays so I have been teaching myself much over the past week but still have much to learn.

I greatly appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Comment: What's the value of `UBound(SplitData)` when it fails ?  Seems like your input array might be smaller than you expect.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the line throwing the error, you can examine the contents of `SplitData` using the Watch window: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I am using this but the issue I'm now having is that the text file from which I'm reading has over 8,000 lines in it; consequently, I'm not going to parse through the code line-by-line.  I'm not finding help from existing threads regarding how to determine the value of the watch expression when the code fails.  At this point, I need to determine at value the collection the code is failing.  Please advise how I can use debugging to find this.  Thank you.

Comment: When the code breaks in the error, hit the "debug" button, go to the VB editor, and type in the Immediate window: `? UBound(SplitData)` and press enter.  What do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding an error handling procedure to display a message box stating the line of the text file where the error was occurring.  Once I got this to work, the message box displayed the correct line and I was able to see that starting at column 31 there was a duplicate entry with blank row values from column 31 to the last column.  Once I deleted that line with the empty values, my code worked fine.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would recommend staying away from using `ReDim` in a loop, as it is quite a costly process. The application has to create a new memory space as large as the redim, then move all data from the old array to the new array, then update the pointers to look at the new array, then garbage collect the old array. In this case, I would recommend using a collection object.

However, that doesn't answer your question.

I cant get the same error when I run your code, unless I try to write to an undeclared array or outside of the bounds of an array. Perhaps you are running out of array memory because of the `ReDim` process, but I don't really use ReDim at all in my code because I have found that it causes more problems than it solves.

Anyway, here is how I would do this with collections:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Declare variables
    Const CMMData As String = "\\ATSTORE01\CMMData\21064D\21064D-OP400.dat"
    Dim strSN As Collection
    Dim strSet As Collection
    Dim strFF As Collection
    Dim strVHCC As Collection
    Dim LineData As String
    Dim SplitData() As String
    Dim LineIter As Long

    Set strSN = New Collection
    Set strSet = New Collection
    Set strFF = New Collection
    Set strVHCC = New Collection
    'Populate Set Number Listbox
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(CMMData, ForReading)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                LineData = .ReadLine
                SplitData = Split(LineData, ",", 154, vbTextCompare)
                'Extracting Serial Number
                strSN.add SplitData(0)
                'Extracting Set Number
                strSet.add SplitData(1)
                'Extracting Final Flow Area
                strFF.add SplitData(14)
                'Extracting /V/ To Hook CC
                strVHCC.add SplitData(31)
                Set_Select.AddItem SplitData(1)
                LineIter = LineIter + 1
            Loop
```

Apologies if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the advice which I did incorporate.  I do however continue to experience the same issue wherein the error "Subscript out of range" comes on the line "strVHCC.add SplitData(31).  I'm continuing to mess with the debugger but any ideas would be appreciated.  If it is the system memory that is the issue, is it as simple of a remedy as upgrading the RAM on my computer?